# Address of the pointed element whatever the iterator type/pointer is passed

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, object-address

What would be the most generic syntax for the following function :

```
template<IteratorType> void myFunction(const IteratorType& myIterator)
{
    _ptr = &myIterator[0];
}
```

It take an iterator myIterator (it can be a raw pointer) and the goal is to assign the address of the object pointed by `myIterator` to a raw pointer `_ptr`. Currently I use `&myIterator[0]` but I realized that only random access iterators have the operator [].

So is there a syntax that will work with all type of standard iterators and pointers ?

Comment: This might be a bit trickier than what you are showing in the case there the stored element overrides `operator&`...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: [Indeed](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Address_Of) (although these days we've got `std::addressof` rather than that gibberish)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can dereference pointer and then take address of object.

```
template<IteratorType> void myFunction(const IteratorType& myIterator)
{
    _ptr = &(*myIterator);
}
```

Comment: Note that this will fail if the stored object overloads `operator&` (yes, you should not overload `operator&` yet it is allowed in the language)

Comment: No need for parentheses in `&*myIterator`.

Comment: C++20: `std::to_address`.

Answer (score 30):

According to standard * operator return a reference so in my opinion the best way is `&*myIterator`, but since the class may overloaded the & operator the best way is `std::addressof(*myIterator)` that work for all classes

Comment: +1 for std::addressof. If there is no C++11, one can use boost::addressof.

Comment: Only forward iterators promise to return references, input and output iterators can return proxy objects, which `&` is inappropriate for.

Comment: You must guarantee that whatever iterator you apply that to, must be valid. I.e. a non-end iterator.  Otherwise... you know... demons.

Answer (score 9):

All iterators are required to have `operator *` (24.2.2:2), so you can write

```
_ptr = &*myIterator;
```

However, this is not valid for output iterators, where `*r` is only valid on the left hand side of an assignment operation (24.2.4:2).

Also note that it is not necessarily true that `*r` will provide a value that `&` can sensibly be applied to; the specialization `std::vector<bool>` (23.3.7) has a `reference` type that is not `bool &`, for example.  In your case the assignment `_ptr = &*myIterator` would catch this, assuming that `_ptr` is an appropriate pointer type, and you would get a compile failure.

Comment: You must guarantee that whatever iterator you apply that to, must be valid. I.e. a non-end iterator.  Otherwise... you know... demons.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you guys are all alive right now. If your iterator is an iterator for `std::vector`, there is a nicer way to get the address that the iterator is holding. You can use:

```
auto *ptr = myIterator._Ptr;
```

I hope I could give a proper answer to your question.

Comment: This unfortunately is not a portable solution. Any identifier starting with '_' followed by a capital letter is reserved as an implementation detail and isn't guaranteed to be consistent in future versions of even the same implementation. In short, don't use it.